# revert sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1 command

Tags: linux, debian, microsoft-teams

I was trying to install Microsoft Teams on Debian 9 and faced some issues. I read an answer where someone suggests to

`sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`

Afterwards, I saw that this is a critical configuration for the system, and I want to change it to the previous state. Is `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone` a variable, and how can I see its value? If it is a variable, which is its default value and to what should I change it?

My questions are basic, but I am a new Debian user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the unprivileged user namespaces with:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0
```

To check it:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone
```

Comment: Doesn't work for podman: 
`cat /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone; podman run -it docker.io/golang:1.20.7-alpine3.18 id -u` prints '0' and '0'.

Comment: It seems existing processes can keep their namespaces. In my case, `pkill podman` solved it.